# Returns inside ifs confuse Java

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I have these two methods and Java can't find the "return" in getNumEmails(). All of them are in the same class, which only has static methods

```
private static int posSymbol=0;
private static int cont=0;
private static String text=null;


private static int getPosSymbol(){
     posSymbol=text.indexOf('@',posSymbol);//if there is no symbol, returns -1
     return posSymbol;
}

//Main calls this method
public static int getNumEmails(String completeText){
     text=completeText;

     while(posSymbol!=(-1)){

         posSymbol=getPosSymbol();

         if(posSymbol!=(-1)){
              cont++;
              posSymbol++;
         }//close if
         else{
              return cont; //It seems that it doesn't reach the return always
         }//close else
         }//close while
}//close method
```

I know that the solution is simple, to delete the "else" and put the return cont; after the while. But I want to know why Java thinks that getNumEmails() could end without returning anything.

Comment: It would certainly exit without the return if the value of getPosSymbol() was -2 or was never -1...

Comment: What makes you think it would always return something? The `else` clause may never get executed.

Comment: @Kendrick. true, but the compiler isn't going to go into that level of examination. It's just seeing an `else`.

Comment: @Arkonor - So you know, there are serious potential issues with this code.  The nastiest of which is if you attempt to use this multi-threaded.  The most annoying of which is that it can't be run twice (in some cases).  Also, don't put close-bracket comments; most modern IDEs will highlight open/close bracket pairs, your methods should _not_ be long enough for them to be necessary, and they run the risk of becoming out-of-sync.

Comment: @Kendrick. getPosSymbol can't return -2 nor neverending values because. a) indexOf() returns -1 or a possitive value if it finds a match for the symbol. b)I doubt that the string it receives could not to have an end (maybe capturing a text which is broadcasted in streaming or something weird, but in my case the source of the text is the keyboard input)

Comment: @X-Zero. Yeah, it's true, I didn't know about multi-thread executions, but I don't know what "it can't be run twice (in some cases)" means... I'm a very beginner in Java. Also, the comments are not in my source code, it typed them here to make clear the blocks of code

Comment: @Jonathan M. The only way to not to execute the "else" is to have posSymbol with different values than -1. But those values are given by the indexOf() of getPosSymbol(), and that's not possible because every string have an end. So at last it will return -1

Comment: @Arkonor, true, but the compiler is not sophisticated enough to know that.

Comment: @Arkonor - Actually, your code can't be run twice _at all_ (didn't look hard enough initially).  Once `posSymbol` is set to `-1` (either becuase a `String` was passed **without** a `@` symbol, or end-of-string is reached), no further processing can happen; this is due to the condition in the `while` loop, and the fact that the value of `posSymbol` will be retained between runs (unnecessary).

Comment: @Arkonor - Oh, I'm not completely convinced that searching for `@` symbols alone is the best way to net you email addresses; it's going to depend on your source, of course.  In any case, I'd probably attempt some sort of loose regex.  Running it in with a `Matcher` (a la Matt's answer) would help some with performance implications of using regex (As opposed to `indexOf()` every time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is about the compiler complaining `This method must return a result of type int`.

While compilers can sometimes determine if a function will reach the return statement, this is not always the case. It is mathematically impossible to statically determine the dynamic behaviour of a program.
This is called the "Halting Problem" in computer science; it is impossible to determine, in the general case if a program will or will not terminate.
So even though you can determine that the method will always reach one of your `return` statements, the compiler may not be able to do so.

Comment: I suspected that the program may had a problem finding the return because it only considered the method itself (without any other data outside the method) or it tried to verify the access to that return doing black box tests (using random values or something) Now I know the truth, thank you. BTW, I wonder if the compiler can process this code even if it can't find the return (probably not, but who knows...)

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it. If the program would have been more complicated, I could have had a lot of problems to find another way to solve it. In this case, I just have to put the "return" after the "while", but in another program it couldn't be feasible

Comment: BTW, how can I use the return key without adding a comment by mistake XD

Comment: As others pointed out, in this particular case there actually is an execution path where the `return` is never encountered. Technically speaking, the compiler _can_ find the `return`, it cannot determine all execution paths. In more complicated algorithms... well, solving those things is just another part of programming, isn't it?

Comment: But you can't avoid the entrance in the "while", the posSymbol is set to zero before that "while" is encountered. I also tried to set it to zero just before the while and still it was giving me problems

Answer (score 2):

It *can* find the return in the else clause. The problem is you need to have a return for all execution paths, even the one when posSymbol is equal to -1, since when posSymbol is equal to -1 you never enter the while loop.

Hence you need a return after the while statement.

Comment: But getPosSymbol(), which is inside the while loop, can return -1 value after the while condition was checked.

Comment: But that's not how you write code. The while statement has a scope which will never be executed unless the condition in the while clause is met. Since the return statement is in the while scope it will not be executed for that reason.

Comment: I can assure you that I tried to set posSymbol=0 just before the While and still it didn't work

Comment: That's not the point. The compiler can not deduce that it will never leave the while loop in any sequential loop, so it still *needs* a return statement after that scope. The compiler does not do any analysis to check if a condition of a variable is always true or always false, it knows that given that you have a while, there should be a return statement in any the statements following it, because your method declaration states that a value should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler is not able statically (at compile-time) verify that the `while` loop gets executed at all (`posSymbol` could be `-1` upon the first invocation). Hence the error.

In general it's not a good idea to keep looping state in member variables. What if more than one Thread executes your method (e.g. in a Webserver)? In the long run it's easier to track down bugs if your code does not modify global state:

```
public static int getNumEmails(String completeText) {
    int count = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@").matcher(completeText);
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how those methods work. Please, could you explain them? BTW, I never thought about multiple users running this program at the same time. I have to take that into account in the future.

Comment: This code tries to find how many `@`s there are in `completeText` by using a regular expression. You can look it up here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `return 0;` after the "//close while".

Comment: It could happen that the method returns 2 different values before it ends. It could crash the entire program. Sorry but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: A method can only return one value. Return means the method exits, it will not run anymore.

Comment: A break only exists a block like for/while loops or switch/case conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but here's a much safer version of the method with no static variables.

```
//Main calls this method 
public static int getNumEmails(String completeText)
{
    int posSymbol=0, count=0;
    while(posSymbol!=(-1))
    {           
        posSymbol=completeText.indexOf('@',posSymbol); //if there is no symbol, returns -1
        if(posSymbol!=(-1))
        {
            ++count;
            ++posSymbol;
        }//close if
    }//close while
    return count;
}//close method
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end. I realized that the else also means that the program ends. Therefore I can put the return after the while to be sure that the program always encounters a return.

Comment: @Kendrik - Agreed, this is much safer.  However, how about putting the `indexOf()` call inside the condition-check for the `while` loop?